# Using Excel to find specific dates within a long list of dates

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I've used an algorithm to generate a list of events, with each event expressed as a date (YYYY,MM,DD). In order to verify the accuracy of the algorithm I have to compare my list of generated events to a list of manually verified events. I am hoping to use excel to do this. Here is the list of manually verified events. They are in random order.

```
2003    8   11
2012    11  19
2005    6   17
2007    8   26
2002    8   6
1999    10  11
2001    2   10
2012    9   16
1998    9   17
1997    9   21
2012    9   30
2002    9   21
2014    6   2
2002    7   21
2012    11  18
2008    11  7
2007    10  3
2002    5   24
1998    7   18
2003    3   28
2005    9   29
2012    8   19
2011    1   29
2009    12  24
1998    9   26
2011    1   25
2010    3   26
2007    5   31
2010    1   28
2003    9   23
2009    2   21
2010    8   14
2000    1   29
2001    7   13
2006    7   10
2004    5   21
1999    5   29
2002    6   15
2007    10  4
2008    8   21
2000    9   6
2002    1   8
2005    10  14
1998    2   17
2008    12  10
2004    10  19
2005    3   5
2010    8   19
1997    8   18
2006    7   12
2008    3   27
1999    3   5
2001    10  6
2012    9   4
2009    6   14
2000    8   19
2002    10  29
2014    4   17
2001    11  17
1998    10  3
2009    2   15
2004    5   3
2014    3   16
2012    4   21
2009    2   24
2002    7   1
2002    8   1
2010    2   13
2004    9   16
2013    10  6
1999    4   19
2009    1   30
2005    5   16
1999    3   4
2012    9   13
2006    4   12
2013    9   15
2001    11  2
2011    1   3
2004    12  23
2001    11  16
2010    7   17
2004    2   21
2011    12  26
2013    8   30
2005    1   16
2008    8   3
2007    10  13
2004    8   27
2003    10  17
2001    4   20
2003    11  6
1998    12  26
2008    9   22
1997    11  12
2006    7   5
2014    4   5
2014    4   24
1998    8   20
2010    10  27
2006    7   30
1998    3   17
2008    12  31
2014    4   19
2003    3   22
2008    10  3
2007    9   28
2010    4   3
2006    11  17
2014    1   3
2012    7   26
2005    3   24
1999    8   20
2010    10  21
2009    4   16
```

The events generated by my algorithm are in the same format (year, month, day) and there are about 3000 events. Sample data below.

```
2000    3   23
2000    3   28
2000    3   31
2000    4   1
2000    4   2
2000    4   3
2000    4   4
2000    4   12
2000    4   18
2000    5   1
2000    5   4
2000    5   5
2000    5   24
2000    6   20
2000    7   25
2000    8   7
2000    8   20
2000    8   22
2000    8   26
2000    8   27
2000    8   28
2000    8   29
2000    8   30
2000    9   1
2000    9   3
2000    9   4
2000    9   5
2000    9   6
2000    9   7
2000    9   15
2000    9   20
2000    9   21
2000    9   24
2000    9   25
2000    9   29
2000    9   30
2000    10  2
2000    10  4
2000    10  5
2000    10  10
2000    10  11
2000    10  12
2000    10  14
2000    10  17
2000    10  18
2000    10  19
2000    10  21
2000    10  22
2000    10  23
```

If my algorithm was accurate, the top set of data shown should be a subset of the second set of data. Is there some way of using excel to efficiently search for the occurence of each maunally verified date within the larger data set? If so, can Excel tell me which days in the top data set are included in the second data set?

Comment: Assuming your data is in columns A,B, and C, in column D use `=DATE(A2,B2,C2)` to make a regular excel date value. Do this for both sets of data. Then, for the subset of data, use something like `=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D2,origdataSht!$D$2:$D$2000,1)),"Not Found","Found")` where origdataSht is the name of the sheet with your original data. EDIT: if your data is not in order, the lookup should be `VLOOKUP(D2,origdataSht!$D$2:$D$2000,1,FALSE)` so it looks for an exact value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data you provided, and the formulas in the comment I made above ...

[image: original data looking at new data]

[image: new data looking at original data]

Comment: Hi OldUgly, thanks for your response. I've attempted to implement as you described. I have a couple of questions though. When you created the dates, your years are represent as two digits, eg 07 instead of 2007. When I attempt date function it gives me four digits (e.g. 2007). Will this mess up the code as you've suggested?

Comment: Also, when I implement the code it produced almost entirely "found" but when I checked manually there were many instances where it said found where that date did not actually exist in the first data set. In your formula, what is the point of the part that reads $D$2000?

Comment: If i specify False for vlookup it seems to function better, as you pointed out in your comment

Comment: The number of digits used to represent the year is determined by the format of the cell - it does not change the value of the cell, therefore it will not affect how the vlookup works. Specifying FALSE in the vlookup will be necessary in order to prevent incorrect results.

Comment: $D$2000 is the last cell in the range to lookup. I pulled it out of the air as an example. Your formula will use whatever your last cell is.